# Swift 3 - How can i extract elements from a json?

Tags: json, swift3

Hello i want to extract certain elements from a json .
**CODE:** .

```
var datas:[Usuario]?

    struct Usuario : Codable {
        let correo: String?
        let contrasena: String?

    }

    let urlString = "http://localhost:8080/swiftdb/logear.php"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }
        //Implement JSON decoding and parsing
        do {
            //Decode retrived data with JSONDecoder and assing type of Article object
            let articlesData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Usuario].self, from: data)
            //Get back to the main queue
            DispatchQueue.main.async {



            }

        } catch let jsonError {
            print(jsonError)
        }


        }.resume()
```

What i want to do, is compare what it is in the json with a textfield ,so it can go to a different view.

Json Contains:

```
[{"correo":"unknown11@hotmail.com","contrasena":"12345"},{"correo":"lalo123@hotmail.com","contrasena":"12121"},{"correo":"kokunz@hotmail.com","contrasena":"11111"},{"correo":"a","contrasena":"a"}]
```

Textfield Contains: {Something which the user writes in in. txtEmail.text Ex.}

Comment: Sorry, nobody except you knows what the JSON contains, what the text field contains and what the comparison conditions are.

Comment: @vadian Updated...

Comment: also you are asking the question with `Swift4` but tagged with `Swift3`. Maybe you can edit this situation, but its not necessary I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Before the answer, you can check the Apple Reference about JSON and parsing . https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

```
if let dictionary = netoxJsonVariable as? [String: Any] {    
    for (key, value) in dictionary {
        // access all key / value pairs in dictionary
        // I am not sure that you can reach key with string but I think you are searching for this. 
        //if(value == "searchedMailAddress"){//then}
        //if(key == "correoLikeKey"){//then}
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any' and 'String?

Comment: OK @Netox, you must convert the type of `Any` for the value, key is always `String` so there will be no problem, and your value properties are always `String` I guess that I seem in your code. You can write like this: 
`if((value as! String) == "searchedMailAddress"){//then}`

Comment: I added a print("it works") after the if so i can check if it works or not, it doesn't display nothing

Comment: @Netox before the if checking, is json data printable ? I mean can you print it or is it `null` ?

Comment: @Netox is your JSON file correct ? `{"correo":"a","contrasena":"a"}` in here, there have 2 key and 2 value. I guess your JSON is broke.For every item in between the brackets you code the json like this:  
`{"correo":"a"},
 {"contrasena":"a"}`. Can you check it out ?

Comment: Yeah i check it out and still didn't work , i tried with a for statement and it worked. Anyways thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

I used a for statement so

```
 let {newVar} = self.{yourJson}

                for item in {newVar}! {
                    let {anotherVar} = item.{field}
                    let {anotherVar2} = item.{field2}
```

Comment: also you can use item[{field}]

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer to your question or is this just more information? If this is just more detail, please delete this "answer" and update your question as needed. If this is meant to be an actual solution to your question then you really need to fix it because it makes no sense.